# php unpack() with H* or bin2hex() stripping of leading zeros

Tags: php, unpack

I have some binary data with leading zero bytes, but when I unpack this data and dump it as a hex string, I seem to have lost these bytes. What am I doing wrong?

**More details...**

I am integrating a GPS device data in php.

The data coming to the device is in binary format and i am using

```
$arr = unpack("H*", $input);
```

I am getting the data as

```
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

or 

2d08010000014b275faaa000328e1e060d3edd1300d001080d000000050301000200f000020900124231e400000100002144
```

This is a a wrong format of data as the leading zeros are all stripped of.
According to integration document, the data will start with

```
Four zero bytes (0x00)

4B AVL Data Length in the format 0000xxxx
```

The correct format of the previous 2 data should have been

```
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

and 

000000000000002d08010000014b275faaa000328e1e060d3edd1300d001080d000000050301000200f000020900124231e400000100002144
```

Note the 4B leading zeros and 4B data length with zero padded.

when i use

```
$arr = bin2hex($value)
```

it gives me the same result.

But i am sure that the data is there in the binary and i am unable to render the leading zeros.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you show how you are dumping the result? You are doing the unpack and then just echo bin2hex($binaryData); ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with test data like hex2bin('0000000012345678'), so I suspect that maybe something has gone wrong which whatever is collecting the binary data?

Comment: Also, unpack or bin2hex do not strip any data: http://3v4l.org/9iLUm

Comment: works for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33ffda203e27b58669e2b2a224ff3661824b4263

Comment: the data is coming from a device in binary format. So when we unpack it using H*, need to get the data zero padded as per the documentation but that is not coming.

Comment: @sectus i need to know the option to unpack so that leading zeros are all maintained

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Its  not about parsing the zero padded string but a data coming from device in binary format and when i unpack it, i am not getting it zero padded My subsequent coding will depend on the data being padded with 4B zeros and 4B data length. looking for option in unpack or any other function that would return me the zero padded string from binary data

Answer (score 0):

On review of codes noticed that i was doing the binary data.

```
$input = trim($input);
```

which created the problem.

Commented the code and the unpack returned the exact format needed